# Memory Mapped File C# - Multiple Threads Creating MMF at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-mapped-files

I have an issue when multiple threads are creating MemoryMappedFile at the same time.

```cs
MemoryMappedFile memoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("UNIQUE ID", 
length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = memoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor();
accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.Write(0, length);
accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.WriteArray(4, buffer, 0, length);
```

and the code that reads this is:

```
MemoryMappedFile memoryMapped = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(args[2], args[3]);
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = memoryMapped.CreateViewAccessor();
int size = accessor.ReadInt32(0);
if (size < 1) {
    return;
}
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReadArray(4, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

There are many processes and multiple threads, one process where many threads write and many processes with 1 thread only for reading. Meaning they can create and read memory simultaneously.

What happens is sometimes the threads that access the memory zone for reading, read 0. Only some of the processes actually read data from the memory region, and the others return a size of 0, meaning the region is empty.

Shouldn't the UNIQUE_ID be enough to solve this issue? What steps do I have to take in order to allow multithreading to work?

Comment: "I have an issue" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: @HansPassant, I clarified the question. Too much re-writes while submitting ended up with me deleting the issue itself.

Comment: Still not very clear. there are various processes and threads and some of them are running some of the shown code, but how and when is entirely unclear. Try to create a [mcve] that tries to demonstrate the issue. (I appreciate that when it's a timing issue so that it doesn't always happen, this is more difficult, but still, at the moment we have no means of reproducing your issue on our machines because there's too much we don't know)